# About loops in c programming

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num = 0, a;

    printf("Enter a number to check if it is prime or composite:\n");

    scanf("%d", &num);            
    getchar();

    for(a = 2; a <= (num - 1); a++)      
    {
        if((num % a) == 0) {
            printf("Number is composite");    
            break;                             
        }
    }

    if(num == a){   
        printf("Number is prime");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

According to above code a=4 and num=5 so why this code prints "Number is Prime" while "a" is not equal to "num"?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Also, please use indentation.

Comment: What makes you think that `a` is 4?

Comment: `a++` increments `a`, so the `a<=num-1` condition is false (conclusion: `a == num`). Translation: the loops stops when the `a <= num - 1` condition is false. That happens when `a == num`.

Comment: and since you're in main(), if this is in fact your entire program, don't forget to `return 0` or something else to return an int

Comment: There is a long key on the keyboard, it inserts a `' '` character when pressed on the editor, please use it, and make your code more readable. Also, you must return an `int` from main, you're not enabling compiler warnings, which IMHO is an error even for experienced programmers, because it helps preventing silly typos that otherwise would compile and hide an error underneath.

Comment: @iharob: Not sure if an older version of this question had a `void` main or similar, but if you're talking about the missing `return` --- at least some versions of C standard allow omitting the `return` from `main` as a special case. *That said*, it is still very good (both for portability and otherwise) practice to have one.

Answer (score 4):

Since you increment `a` at the end of your `for` loop, once the loop has finished executing (assuming `num` is in fact prime), `a` will be equal to `num`, which means that the output "Number is prime" is correct.